# Execute multiple JS file on NPM script NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bash, npm-scripts

I have a NodeJS app for HTTP call managment
I must execute one JS file (`./src/starter.js`) before real app starts (`./src/boot/index.js`)

This is my `package.json` file:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16.0.0",
  "npm": ">=8.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon",
  "build": "npm-run-all clean transpile",
  "server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./dist/boot/index.js",
  "server:stage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=stage node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./dist/boot/index.js",
  "server:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./dist/boot/index.js",
  "server:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./dist/boot/index.js",
  "transpile": "babel ./src --out-dir dist",
  "clean": "rimraf dist",
  "build:css": "node-sass --include-path scss scss/app.scss public/css/app.css --output-style compressed",
  "watch:css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build:css\"",
  "watch:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./src/boot/index.js"
},
[...]
```

And this is my `nodemon.json` (Nodemon configuration file):

```
{
  "exec": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:dev watch:css",
  "watch": [
    "src/*",
    "public/*",
    "scss/*",
    "lowdb"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "docker",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

How can I run "`./src/starter.js`" file before the "dev" script (in terminal: `npm run dev`)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"dev": "./src/starter.js && nodemon",
```